# Reactjs: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I know the issue were posted a lot of times but none of those solutions works for me.. Im new in react and it seems hard to figure out.

After build my project in chrome there is only white screen and error:
[image]

I think it's becouse jsx isnt traspiled to js.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve",
    "build-accept": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack",
    "build-production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.8",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.21.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  }
}
```

bebelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",

  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Build runs successfull but in console i see:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: I doubt error is in any of these shared code. It should be in your main codes not this.

Comment: I'm not sure this error happened in these two files. It occured in your components maybe. A great way to look at your problem is adding eslint to your code. It will show you the syntax error or you can comment / uncomment your components mostly the recent ones. And see if you can find the culprit.

Comment: Please share error stack trace at least.

Comment: the error appears i chrome console

Comment: Sounds like you are expecting JSON and you have HTML

Comment: there was a "<" placed somewhere in your js file the one that loads first when you open the app. Pretty sure it was written in the error code as well as to which js file and which line it is located. Check for it